# Generating buttons side by side not working with display:inline-block

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, ngfor

I'm generating buttons using Angular and the buttons are one on top of the other rather than side by side

```
<div *ngIf="response">
   <div *ngFor="let hit of response.hits.hits">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" style="display:inline-block">{{hit._source.keywords[0].keyword}}</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `style="display:inline-block"` as well as `style="display:inline"` and they both end up one above the other.
Does it have to do with the way `*ngFor` works or is there some other CSS style i could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stacked vertically because you generate a series of `div`, which are block elements.

You should apply the `ngFor` loop to the button:

```
<div *ngIf="response">
  <button *ngFor="let hit of response.hits.hits" ... style="display: inline-block">...</button>
</div>
```

or apply the `display` style to the inner `div`:

```
<div *ngIf="response">
   <div *ngFor="let hit of response.hits.hits" style="display: inline-block">
      <button...>...</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using bootstrap so you just need to encapsulate these buttons inside **btn-group** :

```
<div *ngIf="response" class="btn-group">
   <button *ngFor="let hit of response.hits.hits" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" >{{hit._source.keywords[0].keyword}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah that's how it was originally when I had them hard coded but now I'm trying to generate them dynamically. Is there a way of doing that with bootstrap? If not I might need to not use bootstrap for this part.

Comment: yeh just add this class `d-inline-block` to your buttons, this will make your buttons displayed at same line

Answer (score -2):

```
 <button style="float:left" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" style="display:inline-block">{{hit._source.keywords[0].keyword}}</button>
```

Comment: Add some explanation so everybody can understand what is the solution!

Comment: Also, you have two `style` attributes

Comment: Unfortunately all that did was move the buttons to the left but they're still on top of each other lol

Comment: If you add css ine (float: left) to the objects that you want to be placed side by side in css or style, the next object comes to its right (float: right) and it comes to its right. sorry for the bad points: D

Comment: Please [edit] the answer if the duplicate style attributes were a mistake?